# Writing a list comprehension to create a unique list

Tags: python, list

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,7,8]

listB = list()

for x in listA:
    if x not in listB:
        listB.append(x)
```

Is there a way to write the above in a simple list comprehension?

```
listB = []
[listB.append(x) for x in listA if x not in listB]
```

or

```
listB = [x for x in listA if x not in listB]
```

these methods do not seem to work

Comment: `listB = list(set(listA))`

Comment: Do you want the order of elements to be maintained?

Comment: `listB = [x for x in dict.fromkeys(listA)]` should do the trick if you want to retain order

Comment: `listB= list(dict.fromkeys(listA))` will maintain the order of elements.